# Is there a way to read the file name from a URL in Google Drive?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm writing a Python Program in Google Colab, and I want to automatically name a new created excel file based on the input file name. I read the input data through the following code:

```
file_id = '1_abcdefg'
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id': file_id})

downloaded.GetContentFile('exported.xlsx')
```

Is there a way to determine the actual xslx file name in Google Drive from the url '1_abcdefg'?

Comment: As documented, the simple `drive` is just for basic filesystem manipulations, for further manipulations like getting the metadata you need to use other method like using the drive API: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=P3KX0Sm0E2sF

Comment: Are you using PyDrive ? If so, you should be able to access the file name with dict notation as shown [in the documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/filemanagement.html#upload-a-new-file).